# wpdb get_row database query inquiry

Tags: wpdb, get-row

Is this the right way to use get_row with a select *?

```
$_crds = $wpdb->get_row($wpdb->prepare(" SELECT * FROM `mailers` WHERE `id` = %d", $_GET['caId'] ));

$_zipcodes = $_crds->zipcodes;
$_maildate = $_crds->maildate;
```

Is that the right way to pull the values from the database?
I have a lot of records in that table I need to pull, so wanted to do it in one db pull...

but my code appears to not be working.

-Rich

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Placehold to work, you should use $wpdb->query like:

```
$wpdb->query( 
  $wpdb->prepare( "
            SELECT * FROM mailer
            WHERE id = %d
        ",
        $_GET['caId']
    )
);
```

However in my opinion, the best option is to simply validate the get-parameter and than use it in $wpdb->get_results , like:

```
$catId = $_GET['caId'];
if(is_numeric($catId)){
   $_crds = $wpdb->get_results(" SELECT * FROM mailers WHERE id = $catId");

 foreach ($_crds as $_crds) {
   $_zipcodes = $_crds->zipcodes;
   $_maildate = $_crds->maildate;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out how to do it...

```
$_crds = $wpdb->get_results(" SELECT * FROM `mailers` WHERE `id` = %d", $_GET['caId'] );

foreach ($_crds as $_crds) {
  $_zipcodes = $_crds->zipcodes;
  $_maildate = $_crds->maildate;
}
```

That worked, except the %d didn't work, I had to just do it like this:

```
$_crds = $wpdb->get_results(" SELECT * FROM `mailers` WHERE `id` = " . $_GET['caId'] );
```

I don't know why the placehold did not work. crazy. wish it did because that is from the URL so could get code injection...

Comment: If `%d` doesn't work you don't have numeric data, and yes, there is no protection from SQL injection in your code.